# Can I use a variable inside a parameter of a function in py-cord?

Tags: python, function, discord, bots, pycord

## My Problem

I'm trying to use a variable that selects a certain list depending on a user input from the `operation_select` **slash command** in py-cord. Whenever I run the script the `aircraft option` in the `select_role` **command** always has no choices. I expected this because I defined the variable with [ ] already.

```
import shutil
import discord.ext
from discord import Option
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.all())

air = []

@bot.slash_command(name="operation_select")
async def operation_select(ctx,
mission: Option(str, "Select A Mission", choices=\["Night Terror", "Other"\]),

):

    if mission == ("Night Terror"):
        air = [
    
    if mission == ("Other"):
        air = ["1","2"]
    
    
    
    shutil.copyfile("EENight Terror.txt", "Night Terror.txt")
    with open(f"{mission}.txt", "r") as file:
    
        await ctx.respond(file.read())

@bot.slash_command(name="select_role", description="Select you role")
async def role_select(ctx,
aircraft: Option(str, "Select your aircraft", choices=air)

):

    await ctx.send(air)

bot.run(TOKEN HERE)
```

## What I've tried

I have tried using the variable air as a global variable in and outside the functions.

```
if mission == ("Night Terror")
   global air
   air = ["AH64D", "MI24", "KA50"]
```

Yet none of my attempts have worked.

## The actual result

When typing in the `select_role` command in discord the `aircraft option` would have no choices and when typing anything into it and pressing enter it would return with the list**`["AH64D", "MI24", "KA50"]`** I had selected because I had previously ran the `operation_select` command before the select role.

## The result I want

When running the `operation_select` command I want it to change the variables selected list depending on what the user selects. Which will change what `aircraft` you are able to choose when the `select_role` command is ran.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to change what's provided as possible parameters in the slash command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create search options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77000435/how-to-create-search-options)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible to assign a dynamic variable to the command. However there are 2 solutions I can think of.

1. callback functions can be used inside a command. This makes it possible to dynamically search a big pile of results. Of course this can be altered such that the top results are the `aircraft option`, by giving it access through a global variable to `air`
2. use a `discord.ui.View`. This creates a view window. This would require a bit more work, and comes with the benefit of being more flexible. Similarly to the first solution, the variables can be assigned through a callback function while creating the discord View.

The first solution would look like the code snipet below. I did cut it from my discord bot, which is about selecting a city in the world for some reason.

```
AUTOCOMPLETE_CITIES = ["Tokio", "Paris", "London"]

def autocomplete_check(ctx: discord.AutocompleteContext) -> list:
    """Must return a list of strings"""
    return [val for val in AUTOCOMPLETE_CITIES[:25] if ctx.value in val]


@client.slash_command(name="my command", description="oi mate")
async def _my_command(ctx,
                 city: Option(str,
                              name='city',
                              description='Select a city.',
                              required=True,
                              autocomplete=autocomplete_check)
                 ):
    print(city, type(city))
    return await ctx.respond(f'You chose {city}')
```